# What does the idiom "ganglia of society" refer to?

Tags: phraseology

As far as I can tell, "ganglia of society" first appears in John Dewey's Liberalism and Social action, forming part of the phrase "**basal** ganglia of society". Afterwards, I find no instances of basal ganglia, but I find plenty of instances of just "ganglia of society":

- In the book *Empire* by Michael Hardt and Antonio Negri; this is where I first encountered it.
- [In an newspaper article discussing interfaith dialogue in the Philippines](https://www.lastampa.it/vatican-insider/en/2014/06/07/news/philippines-card-quevedo-my-path-to-peace-1.35741668/)
- [In a research paper on community health programs in rural Tanzania](https://nomadit.co.uk/conference/asa2021/paper/59070)
- [In an article on agriculture investment in Nicaragua](https://www.el19digital.com/articulos/ver/titulo:131763-adelante-el-encanto-del-modelo)

None of these sources explain what "ganglia of society" actually refers to. There are some other sources I have omitted because they simply use the expression in quotes of Dewey. It hasn't escaped me that all of the sources I listed are of a left-wing/anticolonial background, so I suppose it might be a Marxist technical term? In medicine, a ganglion (pl. ganglia) simply refers to a bundle of nerve cells.

Comment: Did you look up "basal ganglia"?

Comment: Basal ganglia are neural bundles at the base of the forebrain; pretty much the same as any ganglia - but specifically those at that anatomical location.

Comment: The quotes of course use the phrase metaphorically, but suggest a slur - assorted *stuff*, women and children are *out there* but peripheral.

Comment: Please reproduce the quotes here with a bit of context, I'm not going to buy a copy of *Empire* and then search through it, and the last link seemed to be doing weird things when I clicked it. The Wikipedia article on basal ganglia explains both what aspects of cognition they are connected with and also the history of the name and of ideas about their function. So I'm sure this can be solved with reading comprehension skills, once we have all the material.

Comment: @HotLicks The other uses at the links he posted are not specifically "basal", they just say "ganglia of society".

Answer (score 1):

The usage is based on an analogy between the functioning of the body and the functioning of society.

Here is one of many online summaries of the function of the ganglia in the body:

> [Very Well Health](https://www.verywellhealth.com/ganglia-5104788)
> **Ganglia** is the plural of the word ganglion. Ganglia are clusters of nerve cell bodies found throughout the body. They are part of the peripheral nervous system and carry nerve signals to and from the central nervous system.
> **Ganglia**, Function:
> Here is more about the function of ganglia in the body. Think of ganglia as the relay stations of the body's nervous system: As one nerve enters a ganglion, another nerve exits it. Ganglia play an essential role in connecting the parts of the peripheral and central nervous systems.
> **The basal ganglia** are located in the brain stem, thalamus, and cerebral cortex areas of the brain. Being in the brain, they are part of the central nervous system, not the peripheral nervous system, as other ganglia are. This group of structures is important in regulating voluntary movements.

Poorly functioning or damaged ganglions therefore may impair the functioning of the body in serious ways, leading to various degrees of disability or even death. The basal ganglia play a particularly import role, as above.

The references you give draw an analogy between the body and its susceptibility to damaged ganglia, and society.

Dewey’s use of the term is exemplified by:

> [The Right Way to Flourish](https://www.johnehrenfeld.com/john-dewey-and-the-brain/)
> “…The economic-material phase of life, which belongs in the basal ganglia of society, has usurped for far more than a century the cortex of the social body….”

The Philippines article includes “…forum of bishops and Muslim leaders united with the scope of promoting dialogue in all ganglia of society…”

The Tanzanian article includes “… public health interventions which, while acting on the ganglia of society (maternal and child health)…”

In Nicaragua, “… the growth of wealth thanks to the fury of volatile and speculative capital, to which the privatizations of all the ganglia of society deliver.…”

In all these usages, parts of society crucially involved in wider communication within society or the functioning of society as a whole are likened to the ganglia. The implication is that if these parts are damaged or malfunctioning, the whole of society will be impaired.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think “ganglia of society” is an idiom, particularly. It just displays a figurative use of *ganglia*, which can be used with any relevant noun.

> **ganglion**, *n.*
>  <sub>**Inflections:** Plural *ganglia*, *ganglions*.</sub>
>
> **5.** *figurative*.
> **a.** A centre of power, activity, or interest. Cf. *nerve centre n.* (b) at NERVE *n.* Compounds 2.
>
> <sub>1828    W. F. NAPIER Hist. *War Peninsula* I. i. iv. 61
>   Thus linking his operations together, Napoleon hoped, by
> grasping as it were the ganglia of the insurrection, to paralyze its
> force.</sub>
>  <sub>1850    T. CARLYLE *Latter-day Pamphlets*
> vii. 15    I see new ganglions of human population establishing
> themselves.</sub>
>  <sub>1882    R. L. STEVENSON in *Longman’s
> Mag.* Nov. 73    That scene is the chief ganglion of the
> tale.</sub>
>  <sub>1927    A. H. MCNEILE *Introd. New Test.*
> 294    We must also keep distinct the four chief geographical
> areas in the Church, the ganglions of its system—Rome and the West,
> Carthage, Alexandria, and what may be broadly called the
> East.</sub>
>  <sub>1995    T. J. COLTON *Moscow* iv. 332  
> As the political ganglion of the USSR, it [sc. the Palace of
> Soviets] was to put on all parliamentary and party congresses and big
> political festivals.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>